# Removing categories list from applications menu

Tags: gnome, menu

I have the applications menu from GNOME on my desktop:

[image]

I want to hide the categories menu somehow, even if that means editing the applications menu file itself.

Is this possible without modifying the file? If not, where is the file that I can modify to achieve this, and (bonus points) what modifications should I make?

Comment: `.menu` files reside in `/etc/xdg/menus/` . They are XML formatted. There is `alacarte` to edit menus but I think it won't do what you want.

Comment: @kenn Thanks for the help, I already know about these files. Unfortunately as you've pointed out, they do nothing for removing the left-hand Categories menu